# PHP5-FPM randomly starts consuming a lot of CPU

Tags: performance, nginx, performance-testing, php

I've run into a really strange problem which I am not sure how to debug further. I have an NGINX + PHP5-FPM + APC Amazon Ubuntu instance and there is a website installed on it which is a complex PHP framework. While trying to debug the problem, I've reduced the flow to this: a lot of big classes get included, main objects are created, session is started, array of configs is retrieved from memcached, an XML file is retrieved from memcached, HTML templates are included, output is sent to the client.

Then I use `http_load` tool to put the website under the load of 20 requests per second: `http_load -timeout 10 -rate 20 -fetches 10000 ./urls.txt`

What happens next is rather strange. `top` shows a bunch of php5-fpm processes spawned each taking a few % of CPU and everything runs smoothly, like this:

```
PID USER PR NI VIRT RES SHR S %CPU %MEM TIME+ COMMAND
28440 www-data 20 0 67352 10m 5372 S 4.3 1.8 0:20.33 php5-fpm
28431 www-data 20 0 67608 10m 5304 S 3.3 1.8 0:16.77 php5-fpm
28444 www-data 20 0 67352 10m 5372 S 3.3 1.8 0:17.17 php5-fpm
28445 www-data 20 0 67352 10m 5372 S 3.0 1.8 0:16.83 php5-fpm
28422 www-data 20 0 67608 10m 5292 S 2.3 1.8 0:18.99 php5-fpm
28424 www-data 20 0 67352 10m 5368 S 2.0 1.8 0:16.59 php5-fpm
28438 www-data 20 0 67608 10m 5304 S 2.0 1.8 0:17.91 php5-fpm
28439 www-data 20 0 67608 10m 5304 S 2.0 1.8 0:23.34 php5-fpm
28423 www-data 20 0 67608 10m 5292 S 1.7 1.8 0:20.02 php5-fpm
28430 www-data 20 0 67608 10m 5300 S 1.7 1.8 0:15.77 php5-fpm
28433 www-data 20 0 67352 10m 5372 S 1.7 1.8 0:17.08 php5-fpm
28434 www-data 20 0 67608 10m 5292 S 1.7 1.8 0:18.56 php5-fpm
20648 memcache 20 0 51568 8192 708 S 1.3 1.3 2:51.06 memcached
28420 www-data 20 0 69876 13m 6300 S 1.3 2.3 0:20.89 php5-fpm
28421 www-data 20 0 67608 10m 5300 S 1.3 1.8 0:21.19 php5-fpm
28429 www-data 20 0 9524 2260 992 S 1.3 0.4 0:11.68 nginx
28435 www-data 20 0 67608 10m 5304 S 1.3 1.8 0:18.58 php5-fpm
28437 www-data 20 0 67352 10m 5372 S 1.3 1.8 0:17.87 php5-fpm
28441 www-data 20 0 67608 10m 5292 S 1.3 1.8 0:20.75 php5-fpm
```

Then after some time which can be anywhere between one second and minutes, several (usually two) php5-fpm processes suddenly consume all the CPU:

```
PID USER PR NI VIRT RES SHR S %CPU %MEM TIME+ COMMAND
28436 www-data 20 0 67608 10m 5304 R 48.5 1.8 0:23.68 php5-fpm
28548 www-data 20 0 67608 10m 5276 R 45.2 1.7 0:07.62 php5-fpm
28434 www-data 20 0 67608 10m 5292 R 2.0 1.8 0:23.28 php5-fpm
28439 www-data 20 0 67608 10m 5304 R 2.0 1.8 0:26.63 php5-fpm
```

At this point everything gets stuck and all new HTTP requests timeout. If I stop http_load tool, the php5-fpm will hang there for many minutes. Interestingly enough if I do `php5-fpm stop`, the php5-fpm processes will disappear but any commands that make use of filesystem will have problems executing. E.g. if I try to download a file via ssh, `top` will show the following, taking many minutes to initiate the actual download:

```
PID USER PR NI VIRT RES SHR S %CPU %MEM TIME+ COMMAND
3298 sshd 20 0 7032 876 416 R 75.2 0.1 0:04.52 sshd
3297 sshd 20 0 7032 876 416 R 24.9 0.1 0:04.49 sshd
```

PHP error log usually has this:

```
[05-Dec-2012 20:31:39] WARNING: [pool www] seems busy (you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers), spawning 8 children, there are 0 idle, and 58 total children
[05-Dec-2012 20:32:08] WARNING: [pool www] seems busy (you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers), spawning 16 children, there are 0 idle, and 66 total children
```

Nginx error log is flooded with these entries:

```
2012/12/05 20:31:36 [error] 4800#0: *5559 connect() to unix:/dev/shm/php-fpm-www.sock failed (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) while connecting to upstream, client: ..., server: ec2-....compute-1.amazonaws.com, request: "GET /usa/index.php?page=contact_us HTTP/1.0", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/dev/shm/php-fpm-www.sock:", host: "ec2-....compute-1.amazonaws.com"
```

PHP-FPM slow log doesn't show anything interesting, swapping never happens and I didn't manage to gather any other interesting facts about the problem. I've gone through many iterations of config file changes, the most recent ones being

nginx.conf: http://pastebin.com/uaD56hJF

pool.d/www.conf: http://pastebin.com/mFeeUULC

===UPDATE 1===

site's config: http://pastebin.com/qvinVNhB

===UPDATE 2===

Also just found that `dmesg` reports errors like this

```
[6483131.164331] php5-fpm[28687]: segfault at b6ec8ff4 ip b78c3c32 sp bff551f0 error 4 in ld-2.13.so[b78b5000+1c000]
```

===UPDATE 3===

We've got a new Amazon EC2 micro instance just in case, to exclude possible hardware issues. Also I am using php-fastcgi now to exclude possible fpm bugs. Other differences are minor, I think the only thing that change is Ubuntu->Debian. The same problem still happens except that now server manages to slightly recover after the max_execution_time seconds (and then spikes again).

I tried playing with a separate test.php and I am not sure if it's the same issue but at least in `top` it looks the same. I created a test.php and included a bunch of libs that belong to our framework. The libs don't do anything except for defining classes or including other libs that define classes. I checked with APC and all of this gets successfully served by it. The I started pressuring test.php with 200 requests per second and after some time the same thing happened. Except that now I managed to get some errors saying "too many open files". It doesn't happen always though, sometimes it just starts timing out without outputting the error and a few php processes are stuck consuming all CPU. I played only a bit with it but I think there is a correlation here - by controlling the number of included libs or slightly varying requests/second rate, I can control when the CPU spike will happen. I increased the relevant OS variables but the issue is still there although it takes longer for it to happen (also note that I've set the limits to values N times larger than the total number of requests I do during tests).

```
fs.file-max = 70000
...
*       soft    nofile   10000
*       hard    nofile  30000
...
worker_rlimit_nofile 10000;
...
(reloaded all the configs and made sure the new system vars actually took affect)
```

So the next best and only explanation I can come up with so far is that even though APC is supposed to pull files from memory, internally it is implemented in a way that still uses a file descriptor whenever PHP include-s are called. And either because it releases them with a delay or when at some unfortunate moment too many requests arrive at the same moment, system runs our of descriptors and newly arriving HTTP requests get quickly stacked into a huge queue. I'll try to test this somehow.

Comment: Could you post the nginx config for the site itself? (not your main config)

Comment: Sure, here it is: http://pastebin.com/qvinVNhB

Comment: Had the same problem. in my case the problem was that PHP72-FPM was doing a lot of database queries on a non-indexed table. In my case, the code was incorrectly written. More about how to search for a solution if the problem is associated with mysql should use this option: log_queries_not_using_indexes = ON

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've run a website with similar configuration for many months, with zero down time.  I've had a look at your config, and it looks ok.  That being said, I did my config quite a while ago.

I would consider reducing `pm.max_requests = 10000` to something more reasonable like `pm.max_requests = 500`.  This just means "don't use each instance for more than X number of requests".  It is good not to have this number too high, because doing so gives you resilience with respect of possible PHP engine bugs.

I think the real problem is most likely in your PHP scripts.  It's hard to say without knowing more.

EDIT:
Consider uncommenting `;request_terminate_timeout = 0` and setting it to something like `request_terminate_timeout = 20`.  Your scripts will then be required to complete within 20 seconds.  You will most likely see a change in behaviour, but I think your site might stay live.  That would indicate a PHP script error.

EDIT2: My own php-fpm config is as follows:

```
[example.com]
listen = /var/run/sockets/example.com.socket
user = www-data
group = www-data
pm = dynamic
pm.start_servers = 5
pm.max_children = 15
pm.min_spare_servers = 5
pm.max_spare_servers = 10
pm.max_requests = 500
php_flag[expose_php] = off
php_flag[short_open_tag] = on
```

EDIT3: I spotted something unexpected in your nginx config, but it may be nothing.

You are using `fastcgi_ignore_client_abort on;` which causes problems in worker processes under older versions of nginx.  I haven't seen this problem myself, since I am running a custom compile of a recent version.  Here's the description of the problem on the nginx site:

> In 1.0.2 POST requests are not handled correctly when
>   fastcgi_ignore_client_abort is set to on which can lead to workers
>   processes segfaulting. Switching fastcgi_ignore_client_abort back to
>   default (off) should resolve this issue.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! `pm.max_requests` is one of the configs I've played with a lot, trying many vales anywhere between 200 and 10000. Unfortunately I haven't noticed any changes. I've set `request_terminate_timeout` to 10 and haven't noticed any changes either. Once it got stuck at 100%, I stopped `http_load`, waited for some minutes for it to calm down and then had to shut down PHP5-FPM because it kept consuming CPU.

Comment: @Eugene One thing I am fairly sure about is that the problem isn't on the nginx side, but if you provide the site specific config I'll check through it. In a moment I'll put my working php-fpm config up for your comparison. It looks similar to what you've got. Let me know if you see something there.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try to play with your config values and will let you know how it goes. At this point I am starting to suspect something much more fundamental like HDD problems or some weird OS-level config that enforces some filesystem locks but sadly I lack knowledge in this area to properly debug such issues (I did try but didn't find any indicators of such problems).

Comment: @Eugene Which version of nginx are you using?

Comment: It's `nginx/1.2.4`. The `fastcgi_ignore_client_abort` haven't changed anything. I've also tried your set of php5-fpm configs without any luck. The only thing that has changed is the number of php5-fpm processes reported by the top and two of them eventually got locked as usual. I guess I'll try to create a completely separate test.php file in the attempt to isolate the cause of the issue.

Comment: @Eugene Ok. It's rather late here, so I'll check back in the morning to see if you've made progress. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, it's actually getting late here too so I'll probably make more progress tomorrow.

Comment: Well, I've tried another EC2 instance as well as php-fastcgi instead of fpm and while the weird locking of file system is gone, the problem still happens. The new server does recover some seconds after the problem happens but when spike occurs, everything times out. Still trying to figure out what can be causing it.

Comment: @Eugene Did you test with a simple test.php file, or your full application?  Just wondering whether we can rule the application out... PS. Looks like we should clean up these comments once we figure this out.

Comment: Please check "Update 3" with the latest findings, the issue still remains a mystery. Cleaning up comments is no problem, hopefully we can in fact figure this out. PS. Thanks for following up!

Comment: @Eugene Hmm.. I'm not sure. There are many known conditions under which a PHP process can hang without exiting.  Can you tell me the exact PHP version?  Would you mind seeing if you can reproduce the problem against a known good php file, for instance: <?php phpinfo(); ?>  ?

Comment: This answer was accepted but without an explanation. Does that mean that the third suggestion fixed things?

Comment: @KevinA.Naudé My fpm consuming more CPU usage, almost 99.98%,  How can i  reduced that, how to do better configuration.

Comment: @Rathinam, there are many conditions that can cause your PHP cpu usage to max out, and it may very well relate to factors other than your fpm configuration. Unfortunately, I am not presently able to help you further in diagnosing the problem. I suggest that you post a new question of your own to raise its visibility within the community. Best wishes.

Answer (score 5):

The behavior of PHP-FPM on my Server is the same as you. bottleneck somewhere for sure.
The question turn out: How to find Bottleneck on Nginx - PHP-FPM - Mysql?
The fastest way to find out is: Enable Slowlog for PHP-FPM.
Add the lines below into your php-fpm.conf pool, and make sure the path is existed

```
request_slowlog_timeout = 10
slowlog = /var/log/php-fpm/slow.$pool.log
```

By read the log backtrace, you can find out why PHP-FPM spent so much CPU or timeout. Here is my cases:

```
[28-Dec-2018 14:56:55]  [pool laravel] pid 19061
script_filename = /public_html/index.php
[0x00007efdda4d8100] hasChildren() /public_html/laravel/vendor/symfony/finder/Iterator/ExcludeDirectoryFilterIterator.php:75
[0x00007ffe31cd9e40] hasChildren() unknown:0
[0x00007ffe31cda200] next() unknown:0
[0x00007ffe31cda540] next() unknown:0
[0x00007ffe31cda880] next() unknown:0
[0x00007efdda4d7fa8] gc() /public_html/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/FileSessionHandler.php:91
[0x00007efdda4d7e50] gc() /public_html/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware.php:159
[0x00007efdda4d7d48] collectGarbage() /public_html/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware.php:128
[0x00007efdda4d7c20] closeSession() /public_html/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware.php:79
[0x00007efdda4d7ac8] handle() /public_html/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Queue.php:47
[0x00007efdda4d7930] handle() /public_html/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Guard.php:51
[0x00007efdda4d7818] handle() /public_html/laravel/vendor/stack/builder/src/Stack/StackedHttpKernel.php:23
[0x00007efdda4d76e0] handle() /public_html/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php:641
[0x00007efdda4d7598] run() 
/public_html/index.php:51
```

The backtrace mentions about these keywords:

```
"cookie" "session" "collectGarbage()" "laravel"
```

I keep searching and TADA, Laravel using RANDOM method to clear expired session. And in my config, PHP using SSD to handle Session.
When Sessions number become "very big" This make PHP spent more time to handle => High CPU Usage.

We can have many kinds of bottleneck, 
**we can just know it when we "debugged" it.**

Have a nice investigate.

Answer (score 4):

Simple trick but very usefull to reduce processor usage upto 50%, just edit your php-fpm config:

```
pm = dynamic
```

and change it to:

```
pm = ondemand
```

Comment: this option was in `/usr/local/etc/php/7.1/php-fpm.d/www.conf` for me.. Mac - Homebrew

Answer (score 2):

I'm going through this same problem right now, and wanted to point you to this post:

### [How to determine which script is being executed in PHP-FPM process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15023540/how-to-determine-which-script-is-being-executed-in-php-fpm-process)

It's got to be one of your PHP scripts.  See if you can connect the dots between the runaway process IDs and the .php script file that's holding you up.

Funny, this has been on a server that's been impeccably fast.  I think a WordPress upgrade (plugin or core) might be very responsible.

Comment: Oh, and for what it's worth, my problem was solved by upgrading to the latest PHP.  I had to change to a newer repository in Ubuntu that was more current than the LTS.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  I tried reconfiguring PHP-FPM and NGINX and didn't get very far.  One of our guys disabled v8js.php (http://php.net/manual/en/book.v8js.php) and it fixed the problem.  I suggest disabling any php modules until you find the troublemaker.  Hopefully that helps someone.