# How to determine which script is being executed in PHP-FPM process

Tags: fastcgi, php

I am running nginx + php-fpm. Is there any way how can I know what is each of the PHP processes doing? Something like extended mod_status in apache, where I can see that apache process with PID x is processing URL y. I'm not sure if the PHP process knows the URL, but getting the script path and name will be sufficient.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

After some googling hours and browsing PHP.net bug tracking system I have found the solution. It is available since PHP 5.3.8 or 5.3.9, but doesn't seem to be documented. Based on feature request [#54577](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=54577), the status page supports option `full`, which will display status of each worker separately. So for example the URL will be `http://server.com/php-status?full` and sample output looks like:

```
pid:                  22816
state:                Idle
start time:           22/Feb/2013:15:03:42 +0100
start since:          10933
requests:             28352
request duration:     1392
request method:       GET
request URI:          /ad.php?zID=597
content length:       0
user:                 -
script:               /home/web/server.com/ad/ad.php
last request cpu:     718.39
last request memory:  1310720
```

Comment: Another very useful option is ?html, e.g.: http://server.com/php-status?full&html (it will format the output as html table, which makes it a lot easier to see all running scripts at once)

Comment: how can i access it shoud i add any paramter to nginx config ?

Comment: @babakfaghihian yes, you need to pass that URL (`/php-status` for example) to php-fpm.

Comment: Unfortunately if your PHP app uses URL rewriting (aka 'friendly URLs'), which most MVC frameworks do, then `request URI` will always display as `/index.php`. The actual URL is passed in the `REQUEST_URI` env var which doesn't appear in the status output.

Comment: @Marki555 : Dude, you just saved my life ! I had been chasing some scripts that were eating up memory on my php-fpm container and had no luck with all the methods i had found...until this `http://server.com/php-status?full` That "?full" parameter just brought the light and showed me the faulty URIs/scripts i was looking after. Thank you very much !

Answer (score 15):

PHP-FPM has a built in status monitor, though it's not as details as mod_status. From the php-fpm config file `/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf` (on CentOS 6)

```
; The URI to view the FPM status page. If this value is not set, no URI will be
; recognized as a status page. By default, the status page shows the following
; information:
;   accepted conn    - the number of request accepted by the pool;
;   pool             - the name of the pool;
;   process manager  - static or dynamic;
;   idle processes   - the number of idle processes;
;   active processes - the number of active processes;
;   total processes  - the number of idle + active processes.
; The values of 'idle processes', 'active processes' and 'total processes' are
; updated each second. The value of 'accepted conn' is updated in real time.
; Example output:
;   accepted conn:   12073
;   pool:             www
;   process manager:  static
;   idle processes:   35
;   active processes: 65
;   total processes:  100
; By default the status page output is formatted as text/plain. Passing either
; 'html' or 'json' as a query string will return the corresponding output
; syntax. Example:
;   http://www.foo.bar/status
;   http://www.foo.bar/status?json
;   http://www.foo.bar/status?html
; Note: The value must start with a leading slash (/). The value can be
;       anything, but it may not be a good idea to use the .php extension or it
;       may conflict with a real PHP file.
; Default Value: not set
;pm.status_path = /status
```

If you enable this, you can then pass the path from nginx to your socket/port for PHP-FPM and you can view the status page.

nginx.conf:

```
location /status {

    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/lib/php/php-fpm.sock;

}
```

Comment: yes I know about this status from php-fpm, I am already using it in munin and zabbix monitoring. However it provides only aggregate information and not per-process info.

Comment: Don't think there is much more you can do apart from creating a custom logging solution or setting up access log processing, but that wouldn't give you the detailed information you need such as processing time. I'm sure as PHP-FPM matures they will extend the status reporting.

Comment: Finally I have found that the status page supports per-process info (see my answer).

Comment: what a horrible idea for the developers to make the debugging info available on a path like this. if you are doing this, make sure the url is restricted

Answer (score 7):

cgi command line is more convinient:

```
SCRIPT_NAME=/status \
SCRIPT_FILENAME=/status \
REQUEST_METHOD=GET \
cgi-fcgi -bind -connect 127.0.0.1:9000
```

Comment: Also note that you must add `QUERY_STRING=full` to return what OP is looking for. Changing `SCRIPT_FILENAME` to `/status?full` doesn't work.

Comment: You will still need to enable the status page by uncommenting `pm.status_path`; the advantage to this method is that it doesn't need to be exposed by the web server. `SCRIPT_NAME` and `SCRIPT_FILENAME` should be the same as `pm.status_path` from the `php-fpm.conf` file. That last parameter (`127.0.0.1:9000`) is the connection to the FCGI server, *not* the web server--it should be whatever the `listen` parameter is in that same INI file. If it's a socket, you may need to use `sudo` to connect, in which case also use `-E` to tell `sudo` to pass through the environment variables to `cgi-fcgi`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use strace to show the scripts being run - and many other things - in real time. It's pretty verbose, but it can give you a good overall picture of what's going on:

```
# switch php-fpm7.0 for process you're using
sudo strace -f $(pidof php-fpm7.0 | sed 's/\([0-9]*\)/\-p \1/g')
```

The above will attach to the forked processes of php fpm. Use `-p` to attach to a particular pid.

The above would get the scrip path. To get the urls, you would look at your nginx / apache access logs.

As a side note, to see the syscalls and which ones are taking longest:

```
sudo strace -c -f $(pidof php-fpm7.0 | sed 's/\([0-9]*\)/\-p \1/g')
```

Wait a while, then hit Ctr-C

Comment: This works `strace -f $(pidof php-fpm | sed 's/\([0-9]*\)/\-p \1/g')`